# fs: how do I locate a parent folder?

Tags: javascript, node.js, filesystems

How do I write this to go back up the parent 2 levels to find a file?

```
fs.readFile(__dirname + 'foo.bar');
```

Answer (score 351, accepted):

Try this:

```
fs.readFile(__dirname + '/../../foo.bar');
```

Note the forward slash at the beginning of the relative path.

Comment: I had been trying that with no luck but I just did `fs.readFile(__dirname + '/../../foo.bar');` and it worked.

Comment: I am assuming then that `__dirname` was somthing like `'/foo/bar'` rather than `'/foo/bar/'`.

Comment: The very first '/' in your path: '/../../foo.bar' is crucial. I had '../../foo.bar' which was causing my issue.

Comment: why? just generally why? can someone please explain?

Comment: @eyurdakul If I understand it corrently: `__dirname` may look like `/path/to/your/dir`, if you say `__dirname + ".."` it is `/path/to/your/dir..`, which is a nonexistent directory, rather than `/path/to/your`. The slash is important.

Answer (score 219):

Use path.join http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.10/api/path.html#path.join

```
var path = require("path"),
    fs = require("fs");

fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', 'foo.bar'));
```

`path.join()` will handle leading/trailing slashes for you and just do the right thing and you don't have to try to remember when trailing slashes exist and when they dont.

Comment: this answer with `path.join` is the correct way, the accepted answer should not be followed, it even triggers `eslint` on `airbnb-base preset`, the rule [no-path-concat](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-path-concat) in particular

Comment: 100th upvote. My `__dirname` was `host/src/folder` and I needed `host/folder` and this worked for me, not the OP answer.

Comment: you can take it one step further and do `path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', 'foo.bar')`

Answer (score 104):

I know it is a bit picky, but all the answers so far are not quite right.

The point of path.join() is to eliminate the need for the caller to know which directory separator to use (making code platform agnostic).

Technically the correct answer would be something like:

```
var path = require("path");

fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', 'foo.bar'));
```

I would have added this as a comment to Alex Wayne's answer but not enough rep yet!

EDIT: as per user1767586's observation

Comment: 'foo.bar" should be 'foo.bar'. I tried to make an edit but edits need to be 6 characters minimum (stupid rule if you ask me, prevents us from editing small typos like this).

Comment: I suspect that this is the best answer. Some of the other answers _might_ work for a given individual on a given operating system, but the presence of a specific kind of file hierarchy separator (i.e. the slash) in those other answers makes me wonder how universal they are. e.g. I'm trying to write an Electron app in a platform agnostic manner and, while I haven't exhaustively proved it, I suspect this is the safest way. Thanks.

Comment: This is actually unnecessary, as path.join() [internally uses path.normalize()](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_join_paths) (which transforms all path separators to the current/intended OS format) on the resulting joined path before returning. It can't hurt, though.

Answer (score 64):

The easiest way would be to use [`path.resolve`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_resolve_paths):

```js
path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '..');
```

Comment: indeed the correct solution as you don't need to resolve the folder by joining `../` to the path

Comment: @Yan what is '..' called?

Comment: @gaurav https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23242004/what-is-double-dot-and-single-dot-in-linux

Answer (score 13):

Looks like you'll need the [`path`](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.10/api/path.html) module. ([`path.normalize`](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.10/api/path.html#path.normalize) in particular)

```
var path = require("path"),
    fs = require("fs");

fs.readFile(path.normalize(__dirname + "/../../foo.bar"));
```

Answer (score 12):

If another module calls yours and you'd still like to know the location of the main file being run you can use a modification of @Jason's code:

```
var path = require('path'),
    __parentDir = path.dirname(process.mainModule.filename);

fs.readFile(__parentDir + '/foo.bar');
```

That way you'll get the location of the script actually being run.

Answer (score 8):

If you not positive on where the parent is, this will get you the path;

```
var path = require('path'),
    __parentDir = path.dirname(module.parent.filename);

fs.readFile(__parentDir + '/foo.bar');
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use

```
path.join(__dirname, '../..');
```

Answer (score 2):

this will also work:

```
fs.readFile(`${__dirname}/../../foo.bar`);
```

Answer (score 2):

i'm running electron app and i can get the parent folder by path.resolve()

parent 1 level:`path.resolve(__dirname, '..') + '/'`

parent 2 levels:`path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '..') + '/'`

Answer (score 2):

This works fine

```
path.join(__dirname + '/../client/index.html')
```

```
const path = require('path')
const fs = require('fs')
    fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname + '/../client/index.html'))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can locate the file under parent folder in different ways,

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

// reads foo.bar file which is located in immediate parent folder.
fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'foo.bar'); 

// Method 1: reads foo.bar file which is located in 2 level back of the current folder.
path.join(__dirname, '..','..');


// Method 2: reads foo.bar file which is located in 2 level back of the current folder.
fs.readFile(path.normalize(__dirname + "/../../foo.bar"));

// Method 3: reads foo.bar file which is located in 2 level back of the current folder.
fs.readFile(__dirname + '/../../foo.bar');

// Method 4: reads foo.bar file which is located in 2 level back of the current folder.
fs.readFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '..','foo.bar'));
```