# Node.js parent path from server.js

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

My is there `c:\nodejs\www\project\bin\server.js`

My views are in `c:\nodejs\www\project\views`

Then in my `server.js` I have:

```
.set('views', __dirname + '/views')
```

But the generated path is: `c:\nodejs\www\project\bin\views`

How to get the parent of `bin` folder?

I use Express and Ejs.

Regards

Comment: see this : [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7083045/fs-how-do-i-locate-a-parent-folder][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7083045/fs-how-do-i-locate-a-parent-folder

Comment: I don't understand how to adapt that code for me. I'm a Node.js beginner.

Answer (score 3):

there are two ways of doing this, I can think :

1. `.set('views',__dirname + '../views');`

Or

2. you can use path.join from the path module

   `var path = require("path"),
       .set(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'views'));`

these will get your back one parent in the directory structure to find the file.