# Why Links are different during the creation of Directory and files in Unix

Tags: unix

When I create directory, and type ls -l. It will show 2 links while I create file and check the long listing via ls -l command then it only show 1 link. Can anyone tell me the reason behind it....
[Long listing of Home directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f54JG.png)

Over here you can see file(e.txt) has 1 link while directory (amit) has 2 link....

Comment: Use `/bin/ls -al` in both cases. Be sure that `ls` is not aliased (e.g. in your `~/.bashrc`)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is double dot(..) and single dot(.) in Linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23242004/what-is-double-dot-and-single-dot-in-linux)

Comment: No, its not related to it..buddy

Comment: @codeforester: It's related, but I wouldn't say it's a duplicate. On the other hand, I don't think this is a programming question;  it would be more appropriate for [unix.se].

Answer (score 0):

I always understood the extra link to be due to the "." entry that is created automatically when a directory is created.  That is effectively a hard link to the directory.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I think this is a homework question in Maurice Bach's book.  In older versions of Unix, there was no `mkdir(2)` system call.  You had to `mknod()` (one link) and then make 2 additional links: one from "." to the new node (the second link), and then link ".." to the parent node (changing the parent's link count).  Hence, 2 links per initial directory.  I can't be sure about the exact book ("The Design of the UNIX Operating System"?), but that's why directories on Unix-like file systems have at least 2 links.  It's also why they added the `mkdir()` system call;  the earlier 3-step process was tedious and error prone.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  A file's name is 1 link.  An inode with no links to it is an unreferenced inode, and should be on the free list.  If it isn't, the file system needs an `fsck(8)`.

Comment: If you haven't read them, I suggest either the Maurice Bach book (above), or Leffler and Kirk McKusick's (et al) "The Design and Implementation of the 4.3 Bsd Unix Operating System".

If someone knows of a descent book on Linux, please let us know.

Comment: Oops.  I meant "decent" in my earlier post.  I chose those two books, even though they're old because they are textbooks made for teaching.  They contain a good deal of history and rationale about the design choices made in the systems they describe.