# "rm: "." and ".." may not be removed" message in mac mojave

Tags: macos, macos-mojave, rm, hidden-files

In my `mac Mojave` machine, when I tried to delete a file, it shows the error

> The directory is not empty.

But when I check, there were no files in that directory. When I did an `ls -la`, it shows

> total 0
>
> drwxrwxrwx  330 root  wheel  10560 Nov 23 20:35 .
>
> drwxr-xr-x    3 root  wheel     96 Nov 24 07:19 ..

**I am not able to delete this using commands `rmdir`, `rm -rf`, etc**. I tried all these with `sudo` only.

How can I remove these files?

Comment: What worked for me was `CMD + SHIFT + .` to show hidden files and then simply delete the . / the folder inside of it

Comment: `.` and `..` do not block a directory from being deleted, as they don't really exist at all. It sounds like Ryul above is discussing something with a space in the name after the dot, which is a different matter entirely.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot delete the `.` and `..` they are just symbols.

`.` represents the directory you are in and `..` represents the parent directory.

From the [dot definition](http://www.linfo.org/dot.html):

> This is a short string (i.e., sequence of characters) that is added to
>   the end of the base name (i.e., the main part of the name) of a file
>   or directory in order to indicate the type of file or directory.
>
> On Unix-like operating systems every directory contains, as a minimum,
>   an object represented by a single dot and another represented by two
>   successive dots. **The former refers to the directory itself and the
>   latter refers to its parent directory (i.e., the directory that
>   contains it).** These items are automatically created in every
>   directory, as can be seen by using the ls command with its -a option
>   (which instructs it to show all of its contents, including hidden
>   items).

[*original SO post*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23242061/944070)

Comment: This isn't an adequate answer. Most other commands allow you to use `.` and `..`, such as `cd`. It wouldn't make sense to say "you can't cd to `.` and `..`; they are just symbols." Normally, the `.` and `..` get automatically expanded to the current directory and the parent directory. Why doesn't this work for the `rm` command?

Comment: @PeterSchorn if you want to get into details you can check this https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/90075/457789