# Locating a json file from a child directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I want to access a json file from the parent directory where the files are set up like this

```
- files
  - commands
    - admin
      - ban.js <-- the file I want my json in
  - command_info.json

(yes this is for a discord.js bot)
```

in my `ban.js` ive used these 4 things: 
`const {CommandInfo} = require("command_info.json")`
`const {CommandInfo} = require("./command_info.json")`
`const {CommandInfo} = require("../command_info.json")`
`const {CommandInfo} = require(".../command_info.json")`
and none of them work as they throw the error:
`Error: Cannot find module './dev_commands.json'`

How would I get my `ban.js` to include my `dev_commands.json`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no `...`. :D
So you need to up 2 folders. `../` == up one folder.

```js
const {CommandInfo} = require("../../command_info.json");
```

Check this out for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23242061/1203844

Answer (score 0):

You need to go up 2 times:

```
const {CommandInfo} = require("../../command_info.json")
```

Keep in mind each `..` means go up once (go to the parent directory).

Answer (score 0):

```js
require('../../command_info.json');
```