# Could not find my typescript property under the interface folder in the component.ts file

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular11

My code is something like that:-

I am creating an `book.ts`(property)  under the interface folder, I am here created a book.ts file.but my book.component.ts doesn't find my book.ts property.but if I using an interface(book.ts) in the book.component.ts. then it's working fine.but I want to keep this interface(book.ts) outside my component.ts file. how i access this from my component.

Here is my code:-

app/interfaces/book.ts

```
interface Book
{
    id: number;
    title: string;
    description: string;
    author: string;
    rate?: number;
    dateStart?: Date;
    dateRead? : Date;
}
```

app/component/books.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-books',
  templateUrl: './books.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./books.component.css']
})


export class BooksComponent implements OnInit {

  
  
  public books: Book[];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

when i run my application.then i found this error:-

[image]

Folder Structure:-

[image]

how i resolve this issue.please help.

UPDATE

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Book } from '../interfaces/book'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-books',
  templateUrl: './books.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./books.component.css']
})


export class BooksComponent implements OnInit {

  
  
  public books: Book[];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

```
export  interface Book
{
    id: number;
    title: string;
    description: string;
    author: string;
    rate?: number;
    dateStart?: Date;
    dateRead? : Date;
}
```

New Error:-

[image]

Comment: Please read https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html for future reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not importing `Book` in the component file.

Add `export` in `book.ts`

```
export interface Book {
  // ...
}
```

And import in the component file

```
import { Book } from '../../interfaces/book'
// other imports and code
```

Comment: now found this error error ```TS2307: Cannot find module '../interfaces/book' or its corresponding type declarations.```

Comment: Could please add your updated code in the question?

Comment: @Linkon updated my answer too. It should work now. You had `components/book.component.ts` in question instead of actual path `components/books/book.component.ts` as depicted in the error.

Comment: it works fine now.i would glad if you describe why ```'../../interfaces/book'``` works and why it does not work``` '../interfaces/book' ```.

Comment: @Linkon, I have added link for docs in the comment in the question itself. You can learn about module from there. The double `../` tells that the file `book.ts` is in grand-parent directory (two levels up in the directory tree).

Comment: @Linkon please see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/23242061/11642727 for _single-dot_ and _double-dot_

Answer (score 0):

1. Put book.ts in interface folder
   Write prefix export before interface book.
   Sample syntax

   ```
   export interface Book {}
   ```
2. and now import the interface in component.ts file
   Sample syntax

   ```
   import { Book } from './interfaces';
   ```