# set non acceptable characters as a file name in py3

Tags: python-3.x, file, char, python-imaging-library, draw

I'm trying to create some Images for characters and name them with that character.
this is my char list:

```
letters=["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z",":",",",
     ".","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0","-","_","=","+","`","~","[","]","{","}","<",">","&","*","^",",","|",
     "/","@","#","$","%","(",")",";",":","'","."]
```

It's ok till it arrives to  "." and it throw this error:

```
IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '.'
```

this is my code for create this pngs:

```
for x in letters:
    print("create " + x)
    txtImg = Image.new('RGB', (200, 100), (255,255,255))
    d = ImageDraw.Draw(txtImg)
    d.text((20, 20), x, fill=(0, 0, 0))
    s = io.BytesIO()
    txtImg.save(str(x),"png")
```

how can I solve that?

Comment: '.' and '..' is a special https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23242004/what-is-double-dot-and-single-dot-in-linux

Answer (score 0):

You can not use '.' or '..' as a filename on Unix-like operating systems in any directory, it is used alreay. '.' represents the directory you are in and '..' represents the parent directory, you can see more deails at
[What is double dot(..) and single dot(.) in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23242004/what-is-double-dot-and-single-dot-in-linux)

Comment: yes I know but is there any way to do this? like changing character to assci code or some thing like this?