What are these hidden files that are shown by git bash?
If i do
ls --all

I get this:
./  ../  .git/

So, what do the first 2 "dots" files refer to?

. is the current directory, and .. is the parent directory.

Thought it was some weird hidden file

Note that this syntax even works for URLs on most web servers. For example, if you type the following URL https://stackoverflow.com/questions/../questions/79315727/what-are-these-hidden-files-that-are-shown-by-git-bash it will point back to this question. Because the .. takes you to the parent directory which is stackoverflow.com and then you go back to /questions which takes you back to this very page

Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23242004/what-is-double-dot-and-single-dot
