# NodeJS accessing file with relative path

Tags: node.js, express, fs

It seemed like a straight forward problem. But I amn't able to crack this.
Within helper1.js I would like to access foobar.json (from `config/dev/`)

```
root
  -config
   --dev
    ---foobar.json
  -helpers
   --helper1.js
```

I couldn't get this to work [fs: how do I locate a parent folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7083045/fs-how-do-i-locate-a-parent-folder)

Any help here would be great.

Comment: `..\config\dev\foobar.json`

Comment: It would be better if you can just save your json data in `.js` file (instead of `.json`) And then from the `.js` file `module.exports` it. :)

Comment: @AdityaParab: If you save you JSON file as .json instead of .js then you don't need to module.export it - you can require it directly. JSON file are automatically completely exported (or to put it another way, JSON files are supported by `require()`)

Comment: @slebetman js files are more flexible, JSON requires double quotes, doesn't allow comments, etc.. One could use JSON5 or other similar format, but then you need a lib to read it. Js also allows dynamic data generation, from a function for example

Comment: The real reason to use .js over .json text files is really easy to explain:

comments... ;)

Answer (score 283, accepted):

You can use the `path` module to join the path of the directory in which `helper1.js` lives to the relative path of `foobar.json`. This will give you the absolute path to `foobar.json`.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

var jsonPath = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'config', 'dev', 'foobar.json');
var jsonString = fs.readFileSync(jsonPath, 'utf8');
```

This should work on Linux, OSX, and Windows assuming a UTF8 encoding.

Comment: No need to use  `__dirname`

Comment: @osrpt It's better to use `__dirname` because the path will be correct regardless of the context in which the helper1 script is run (e.g.  `node helpers/helper1.js` will work from the root directory).

Comment: perfect this worked! I didn't us path but __dirname + '/..'

Answer (score 19):

Simple! The folder named `..` is the parent folder, so you can make the path to the file you need as such

```
var foobar = require('../config/dev/foobar.json');
```

If you needed to go up two levels, you would write `../../` etc

Some more details about this in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7165572/1311745) and it's comments

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code here.

Comment: This will only work on json/js file. It will not work on other types of files like xml. Better approach is path.join()

Comment: This is not a very good solution if you are calling the file from another folder. If you structure is src->utils->someUtilFile.js and also have a second file src->logic->someLogic.js and you use ../../utils/someUtilFile.js this will work. but if you are calling someUtilFile.js from a different structure directory this will not work.