# Node.js is unable to find a file in another folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, directory, discord.js, directory-structure

I have a Discord bot I'm maintaining since a year, and a couple of months ago I changed a bit the file structure to clean it up and make it easier for me to know what's going on.

The thing is, whenever I try to request a file (with require) that is in a folder located in the bot's root directory, sometimes it works with `"./"` and other times it works with `"../"`

**The current file structure is:**

```
----commands  
-------commands.js(multiple files)  
----images  
-------halloween  
----------images.png/jpg(multiple images)  
----logs  
-------bot.log  
----modules  
------logger.js  
----settings  
-------config.json  
-emojis.json  
-gifs.json  
-index.js
```

Following the structure above, when for example I try to request one of the halloween images in a command, the logical thing to me would be to use "../images/halloween/image.png", but instead I have to use "./images/halloween/image.png" as if the "images" folder is within the "commands" folder

In one of the commands I have to use:

```
const logs = require("../modules/logger");  
const background = await Canvas.loadImage("./images/halloween/background.jpg");
```

I would like to know why this happens. It really messes with my brain seeing an error saying that a file was not found only because node.js decided that this time the parent directory is `"./"` instead of `"../"`

Comment: Request with what?,  `require`,  `readFile`, or something else.?

Comment: with require, but sometimes I use neither of them, depending on the package I'm using

Comment: Can we see the code that's failing sometimes?..

Comment: I edited the post with the example code

Comment: That's not using `require` to load, it's using something called `Canvas.loadImage`, I'm not sure what that is, but for things like `readFile` that it's likely using try and avoid using relative paths here, as there relative to current working directory, and that can change during program execution.  Instead use `path.join` with `__dirname`..  eg.  `loadImage(path.join(__dirname, './images/halloween/background.jpg'))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your commands file is making file system calls (because you're accessing an image from it), the directory you invoke your script from can matter. Make sure you're using the `path` utility to resolve your file locations. See [NodeJS accessing file with relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32705219/nodejs-accessing-file-with-relative-path) for more details.

Comment: so basically what you're saying is that even though I'm trying to request within the command file, `"./"` can sometimes be relative to the command file and other times to index.js?

Comment: Node will resolve paths relative to the file for you if you're interacting with another javascript file, it will not for other types of files.