# Path.join and/or path.normalize create path with mixed slashes

Tags: node.js, linux, docker, path

I have a website that I'm running integration tests for, on a Linux Docker (Debian).

In the website's API I do this:

```
UPLOADED_FILES_LOCATION="C:\Users\username\Documents\uploadedFiles"
const filePath = "folderName/fileName.jpg";
const filePath = path.join(process.env.UPLOADED_FILES_LOCATION!, filePath);
const fileBuffer = await fs.readFileSync(filePath);
```

Buut, I get this error during the tests:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\username\Documents\uploadedFiles/folderName\fileName.jpg'
```

I tried also like this:

```
const filePath = path.normalize(path.join(process.env.UPLOADED_FILES_LOCATION!, filePath));
```

And like this:

```
const filePath = path.normalize(`${process.env.UPLOADED_FILES_LOCATION!}/${filePath}`);
```

Aren't both path.normalize and path.join supposed to replace slashes (normalize the path)? Why isn't this working?

Edit: I realize the path is a Windows directory, but if you look a the path it still has mixed slashes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#pathnormalizepath)

> The path.normalize() method normalizes the given path, resolving '..' and '.' segments.
> When multiple, sequential path segment separation characters are found (e.g. / on POSIX and either \ or / on Windows), they are replaced by a single instance of the platform-specific path segment separator (/ on POSIX and \ on Windows). Trailing separators are preserved.

In your case `UPLOADED_FILES_LOCATION` should be (or convert it):

```
UPLOADED_FILES_LOCATION="C:\\Users\\username\\Documents\\uploadedFiles"
```

So:

```
path.normalize('C:\\Users\\username\\Documents\\uploadedFiles/folderName\\fileName.jpg')
// C:\Users\username\Documents\uploadedFiles\folderName\fileName.jpg
```

Alternative:

- you can use this package: [app-root-path](https://www.npmjs.com/package/app-root-path)
- or just user relative path: [NodeJS accessing file with relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32707530/11395898)

Comment: So ex. I just tried it with the Linux path and got:

    Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/siteName/dist/downloadedFiles\folderName\fileName.jpg'

...And path.normalize will not replace the slashes in the filePath for me? I mean if I try to join ...dist/downloadedFiles to folderName\fileName.jpg, the \ in "folderName\fileName.jpg" will not be replaced?

Comment: This "folderName\fileName.jpg" thing is stored in the database as a string.