# No such file or directory using fs to load a file in same directory

Tags: javascript, node.js-fs

I am using ExpressJS and NodeJS. I am trying to load a json file from my server as a test. The json file is in the same location as the javascript file that is trying to read the json file but it says it cannot find the file even when i used relative path.

```
fs.readFile('./customers.json', 'utf8', (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log("ERROR: " + err);
    } else {
        jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
        res.json(data);
    }
});
```

The error i get when i go to `localhost:3000/customers`:

```
[0] ERROR: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory
```

Am i using the wrong path i am a bit confused what is wrong here since they are both in the same folder:

[image]

Comment: Paths will be relative to where you ran the process, not the file itself. Check out the accepted answer to this SO for how to find the path relative to the current file: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32705219/nodejs-accessing-file-with-relative-path

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NodeJS accessing file with relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32705219/nodejs-accessing-file-with-relative-path)

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```js
fs.readFile(__dirname + '/customers.json', 'utf8', (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log("ERROR: " + err);
    } else {
        jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
        res.json(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: While this code may solve the problem, you should also explain *why*  it solvels the problem.

Comment: @derpirscher I'm sure the OP will find out for themselves why the code runs (since there's not much of a difference) which will be easier to remember than waiting for someone to explain. What I mean is that learning the difference yourself is more beneficial than letting someone else point it out

Comment: @TachibanaShin from my teaching experience, I came to different conclusions. Just presenting some code without further explanation leads to people just copying and using code without understanding it. And even if someone tried to understand it, they may draw wrong conclusions because they misunderstood something ... And that will lead to  errors when they reuse the code in different situations, where it doesn't fit.

Comment: @TachibanaShin and if a question is tagged with `nodejs-fs` and OP state they are using NodeJS, it's perfectly fine to give an answer that will work in nodejs but maybe not with other runtimes ...