# path.dirname on Windows path is giving `.`

Tags: node.js, electron

I in electron am doing:

```
 path.dirname('C:\\Users\\Blagoh\\Documents\\GitHub\\Screeenshoter\\dist\\electron\\main')
```

That path is the actual value of my `__dirname`. How come it is not giving me  `C:\\Users\\Blagoh\\Documents\\GitHub\\Screeenshoter\\dist\\electron`? I want that `main` part chopped off.

Comment: The nodejs [source for dirname](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/path.js#L717-L719) states that it returns `'.'`, if the passed string has a length of 0 or if it is just a string without any (back-)slashes (just a folder).

Comment: Oh dang, thanks @RoyalBingBong - I see I need to put a filename with it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `main` is a `directory` inside `electron`. Also assuming that you have some file called `index.js` inside `main` folder where you want to have the `path of electron directory`.

So, you can do path.join this way:

```
var mainFolderParentPath = path.join(__dirname, '../');
```

Your original file location:

```
C:\\Users\\Blagoh\\Documents\\GitHub\\Screeenshoter\\dist\\electron\\main\\index.js
```

__dirname will return

```
C:\\Users\\Blagoh\\Documents\\GitHub\\Screeenshoter\\dist\\electron\\main
```

and then inside path.join '../', will chop off the main folder from path. So, you will be left off with:

```
C:\\Users\\Blagoh\\Documents\\GitHub\\Screeenshoter\\dist\\electron
```

Comment: When I do `path.join(__dirname, '../')` it is giving me `./` :(

Comment: @Blagoh For that look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7083067/2284240

Answer (score 0):

Well you obviously didn't read the docs for [dirname](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_dirname_path). It states that it works like the Unix command `dirname` which "strips non-directory suffix from file name", thus you get the `C:\\Users\\Blagoh\\Documents\\GitHub\\Screeenshoter\\dist\\electron`.

What you are looking for is [basename](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_basename_path_ext).

`path.basename('C:\\Users\\Blagoh\\Documents\\GitHub\\Screeenshoter\\dist\\electron\\main')` will give you `main`.

Comment: Hi there, I am trying to get `C:\\Users\\Blagoh\\Documents\\GitHub\\Screeenshoter\\dist\\electron\\`

Comment: @Blagoh, oh wow. I have no idea how I screwed up reading your question. Sorry about that :/